Microsoft Graph APIs - 401 being generated despite access token appearing to be OK - using PHP
Essentially when I make a call to try to retrieve a document from sharepoint via its URL I am seeing a 401 - which I also see if I take the access token and use it within Postman for example.
I have a simple proof of concept app I am developing. The first part of this reads a Sharepoint structure recursively and stores in a database the folder name / filename / filesize / url. This works brilliantly. To make this work, I registered the "app" with Azure and popped the relevant IDs into a configuration file thus
SHAREPOINT_TENANT_ID="f5323574-......"
SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_ID="6718dcf4......."
SHAREPOINT_CLIENT_SECRET="_HG8Q......"
SHAREPOINT_TOP_DRIVE_ID="b!UKVJ......"

The code then starts by getting an access token from MS Graph and then sends this with every subsequent request. The structure of the data returned by each call (when a file is found) contains these data elements (amongst others)
            $credate = $v['createdDateTime'];
            $updatedate = $v['lastModifiedDateTime'];
            $size = $v['size'];
            $name = $v['name'];
            $url = $v['webUrl'];
            $urlSession = $v['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl'];

Now - at this point, the variable $urlSession can be used in a GET request to retrieve the content of the document indicated - and it works flawlessly. However (as I understand it), the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl is only valid for the session and the "persistent" URL is held in the webUrl element - and it is this that we store in our database.
So far, so good.
The second part : my problem arises when I read the database and want to access a document via its URL from Sharepoint. I am using the exact same method to obtain the access token as in the first part and (having checked app permissions etc. in Azure) all looks as though it should work just fine - but of course, it doesn't - I get a 401. This is an example of the output generated by my php:
php sp_get_doc_via_db.php
Decoded JWT Payload:
Array
(
    [aud] => https://graph.microsoft.com
    [iss] => https://sts.windows.net/f5323574-...../
    [iat] => 1721819141
    [nbf] => 1721819141
    [exp] => 1721823041
    [aio] => E2dgYDjxf........
    [app_displayname] => HCAT_API
    [appid] => 6718dcf........
    [appidacr] => 1
    [idp] => https://sts.windows.net/f5323574-d811-........./
    [idtyp] => app
    [oid] => 2b17f89a-407c-............
    [rh] => 0.AUcAdD.........
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder
            [1] => BrowserSiteLists.Read.All
            [2] => Sites.Selected
            [3] => Files.SelectedOperations.Selected
            [4] => Sites.Read.All
            [5] => Sites.ReadWrite.All
            [6] => Files.ReadWrite.All
            [7] => User.Read.All
            [8] => BrowserSiteLists.ReadWrite.All
            [9] => Files.Read.All
            [10] => FileStorageContainer.Selected
        )

    [sub] => 2b17f89a........
    [tenant_region_scope] => EU
    [tid] => f5323574...........
    [uti] => L4C7-..........
    [ver] => 1.0
    [wids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0997a1d........
        )

    [xms_idrel] => 7 20
    [xms_tcdt] => 1575971057
)
Token Expiry (exp): 2024-07-24 12:10:41
11:10:42 Request file - CAS Mural.jpg
11:10:42 https://TOPLEVELDOMAIN.sharepoint.com/sites/path/Shared%20Documents/Archive_Catalogue/Catalogue/4%20Sub-Catalogues/casMural.jpg
Failed to download document. HTTP Status Code: 401
Response: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
header: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
body:

I'm showing the decoded token content as this demonstrates the permissions that the app has been given.
Does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong? I have visited this problem several times over recent days and it's taking too much of my time!
I'm sure the answer will be so simple yet I am unable to think how to find it.
Thought: is this an authorization token and do I now need an access token ? If that's the case, what's involved..?
many thanks in advance,
j
